# Algorithm help - unique encoding of phone numbers

Tags: algorithm, encoding

I have a dictionary of words split into two lists of different lengths, adjectives and nouns. I want to be able to reversibly encode any phone number into a format where I have one or more adjectives followed by a noun.

Examples might be
"+447911123456" => "agile sassy stingray"
"07911123456" => "funky old golf club"

It should have properties like [the avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect), and make relatively even use of all the words in the dictionary.

I've not been able to come up with an algorithm that satisfies all the requirements. Does anyone know how to do this, or where to learn more about doing this sort of encoding?

If it helps, I've made [the dictionary available on github](https://github.com/thehenrymcintosh/encoding_challenge). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This reminds me of what3words.com.  Searching the web revealed many explanations of how they convert lat/long into 3 words.

Answer (score 0):

> reversibly encode any phone number
> How about something like this?

1. Given phone numbers are typically 10 - 14 digits including the international code, we can treat it as a 64 bit integer (up to 19 digits) if we ignore the international dialing code "+".
2. Split the segments into 3 roughly even zones = 21 bits each.
3. XOR each of the zones with a fixed repeating pattern - i.e. 01 for seg 1, 10 for seg 2, 11 for seg 3.
4. Perform a simple encryption that is 21 bits wide... a simple custom one can be developed easily.
5. After these transformations, you end up with 3 numbers.  Use the numbers as keys to your dictionary.  The 3rd block will reference a nouns dictionary.

The purpose of steps 3 and 4 are to obfuscate what you are doing.
For instance, if we had 111 111 111 as our number, without 3 and 4, we might have "happy happy dog".  With 3 and 4, even though segments 1 and 2 are identical, it will result in different words such as "happy sloppy dog".  Instead, we might get a totally different number result in repeated words... i.e. 111 843 111 => "happy happy cat".

Because it is only for obfuscating purposes, these do not need to be terribly "secure"...

Comment: Thanks for your input! Particularly, the XOR process makes sense for reversibly obfuscating the result. 
One of the issues with this process is the assumption  made in step 1 that we can treat phone numbers as 64 bit integers. If we get rid of the + or other valid special characters then information is lost and the process is no longer reversible. The algorithm should be able to process numbers with or without these characters. Another issue is if the first digit is a 0, like all mobile numbers in the uk, as that information would be lost by converting to a 64 bit integer.

Comment: Well, how many reversible special characters can exist in a phone number?  Just the + or leading 0s, correct?  We are still using only 15 or so of the 19 digits that a 64 bit long can support.  So all we have to do is use the upper n bits (except for the sign bit).  i.e. the 2nd bit might be to indicate + or not.  The 3rd -> 5th bit might be used as a count (up to 7) of leading 0s.